# Webscraping with ProxyEgg and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, proxy

I have the following code (I have X'd out my user name and password). The code runs fine however how do I know if its using the proxy IP address to complete this scrape?  I am teaching myself from scratch how to do this so any help is appreciated as I know there is so much to learn!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice
import pandas as pd

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        return Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,
            headers={"User-Agent": "My user agent"},
            meta={"proxy": "http://username:/password@p.proxyegg.com:8080"})


def getProduct_Data(tag):
    url = f'https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number={tag}'

    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    Product_Data = {
    'sku': soup.find("div",{"class":"head2BR"}).text,

    'product': soup.find("div",{"style":"float:left; margin-left:24px; margin-top:8px; margin-right:14px;"}).text,

    'description': soup.find("div",{"style":"min-height:80px; max-height:224px; overflow-y: scroll;"}).text.strip(),

    'price': soup.find("div",{"class":"float_Q"}).text.strip(),

    'features': soup.find("div",{"class":"grey1"}).text.strip(),

    'contents': soup.find("div",{"style":"max-height:28px; overflow-y:scroll;"}).text.strip(),

    'compatiblity': soup.find("div",{"style":"width:960px; margin:auto; padding-top:18px;"}).text.strip(),
    }
    url_list.append(Product_Data)
    return

getProduct_Data('KBR15')
getProduct_Data('W13374')
getProduct_Data('BMR98')
getProduct_Data('W51210')
getProduct_Data('W51211')
getProduct_Data('W92498')
getProduct_Data('W93404')
getProduct_Data('W92899')
getProduct_Data('W51710')
getProduct_Data('W53277')
getProduct_Data('W53379')
getProduct_Data('BSK010M')
getProduct_Data('KSB568')

df = pd.DataFrame(url_list)
df.to_csv('whitelinefull.csv')

print('Fin.')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to test the efficacy of your proxy is to scrape an IP lookup/location site and check that the IP the site detects via the request is the same as the one your proxy is using:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://ip.me/', proxies=proxies, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
assert d.select_one('input[name="ip"]')['value'] == re.findall('(?:\d+\.)+\d+', proxies['https'])[0]
```

The detected IP from https://ip.me/ can be found in `d.select_one('input[name="ip"]')['value']`.

---

It may be possible that instead of an explicit IP in your `proxies` dictionary, a non-IP URL with login credentials might be used instead (which appears to be the case from your post). To check that the proxy provider is working correctly, you can send a request to https://ip.me/ both with and without the proxies and compare the results:

```
d = soup(requests.get('https://ip.me/', proxies=proxies, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
d1 = soup(requests.get('https://ip.me/', headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
assert d.select_one('input[name="ip"]')['value'] == d1.select_one('input[name="ip"]')['value'], "proxy does not seem to be working"
```